Display Angular observable with array data in ionic
Im using Angular 18 with Ionic/Angular v8.0.0 standalone component:
My Service :
getFinds(): Observable<Find[]> {
  return this.http.post<Find[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/list`, {}).pipe(
    delay(500)
  );
}

my feed.component.ts

ngOnInit() {
 this.finds$ = this.findsService.getFinds();
}

and my feed.component.html
<ion-list>
  <ng-container *ngIf="(finds$ | async) as finds; else emptyState">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of finds" lines="none" class="ion-padding-bottom">
      <ion-label>{{item.note}}asdf</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #emptyState>
    <ion-item lines="none" class="ion-padding-bottom">
      <ion-label>Nothing found</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ng-template>
</ion-list>

The service returns data as seen in network tab and via console.log, yet the data is not displayed via my html component file. On the website the emptyState (Nothing found ) is displayed. Im not sure what Im doing wrong and im wondering wether its an ionic issue?
I would expect to see the result array of Finds displayed as an ionic list

You usually get data use the this.http.get, you can use this.http.post to create new data and this.http.put when you want to update existing data.
getFinds(): Observable<Find[]> {
  return this.http.get<Find[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/list`).pipe(
    delay(500)
  );
}


Thank you. I changed the method type to GET. Thank you very much  for improving my code! For transparency I want to mention what was the full reason the code didn't work in my was that the response from the getFinds method returned a paginated result which i didnt handle correctly and the ngFor loop cant handle as its not an array. So i guess always check your data structure.
